# Is it possible to build an rpm package without making a tar.gz archive?

Tags: rpmbuild

For me making a tar.gz archive is excess, because i export source code from svn. Perhaps it is possible to make rpm archive without automatic unpacking of archive? (Perhaps it is possible just to copy files from source folder to build or something like this)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to build a rpm using just the sources instead of tarball](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787716/how-to-build-a-rpm-using-just-the-sources-instead-of-tarball)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a whole ton of documentation on this, but yea you can just list the file if you want to. [Here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging%3aRPM_Source_Dir) is a great discussion on doing this, as well as proper usage straight from Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but if someone needs this answer.. here is a solution.

```
Source1: yate-ucn.conf
Source2: p-cscf.conf
Source3: p-gw.conf
Source4: ucn_version.conf

(...)

install -m 644 %{SOURCE1} %{buildroot}%{_sysconfdir}/yate/ucn/
install -m 644 %{SOURCE2} %{buildroot}%{_sysconfdir}/yate/ucn/
install -m 644 %{SOURCE3} %{buildroot}%{_sysconfdir}/yate/ucn/
install -m 644 %{SOURCE4} %{buildroot}%{_datadir}/yate/api/
echo '<?php global $ucnvers; $ucnvers = "%{version}-%{release}"; ?>' > %{buildroot}%{_datadir}/yate/api/ucn_vers.php
```